# does this ensure i am reading from the ram?

Tags: vhdl, arm, memory, ram, zynq

I at the moment trying to reverse engineer something i made a long time ago but never understood why it is running so slowly.

I have a Zybo board, with an Zynq 7010s chip ons which has dual cortex-A9 processor and a FPGA tightly compacted together.

On the CPU side i made a game, which for each iteration generate an array of decsribing the pixel value of the game image.

=> first question => this array is pretty large, and i am bit unsure where this variable would be stored?.. I just created a variable that had this value.

Next the game image had to be displayed on vga port, for which i how to transfer the data from the PS to PL side. I used the AXI DMA, and transfered it like this:

```
void send_data(char c_map, u32 target){
    //xil_printf("\r\nStarting sending data\r\n");


    /* Initialize the XAxiDma device.
     */
    CfgPtr = XAxiDma_LookupConfig(DMA_DEV_ID);
    if (!CfgPtr) {
        xil_printf("No config found for %d\r\n", DMA_DEV_ID);
        //return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    Status = XAxiDma_CfgInitialize(&AxiDma, CfgPtr);
    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        xil_printf("Initialization failed %d\r\n", Status);
        //return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    if(XAxiDma_HasSg(&AxiDma)){
        xil_printf("Device configured as SG mode \r\n");
        //return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    //Value = 0b11110000000000000000000101000000;

    if(c_map == WALL){
        //bbbbggggrrrr
        Value = 0b11111111111100000000000000000000;
        //Value = 0b00000100000000000000000000000000;
        Value = Value + target;
    }else if(c_map == BALL){
        //Value = 0b10000000000000000000000000000000;
        Value = 0b00000000111100000000000000000000;
        Value = Value + target;
    }else{
        Value = 0b00000000000000000000000000000000;
        Value = Value + target;
    }

    for(Index = 0; Index < MAX_PKT_LEN; Index ++) {
        TxBufferPtr[Index] = Value;
    }

    Xil_DCacheFlushRange((UINTPTR)TxBufferPtr, MAX_PKT_LEN);

    Status = XAxiDma_SimpleTransfer(&AxiDma,(UINTPTR) TxBufferPtr,
            MAX_PKT_LEN, XAXIDMA_DMA_TO_DEVICE);

    if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        xil_printf("No XST_SUCCESS \r\n");
        //return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    while (XAxiDma_Busy(&AxiDma,XAXIDMA_DMA_TO_DEVICE)) {} //wait
}
```

In the PL i create a block ram as such

```
type RAM is array (0 to ADDR_WIDTH+1) of std_logic_vector (DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
signal mem : RAM := (others => (others => '1'));
```

Which supposedly should be a block ram, and then inside my VGA driver fill in my memeory block with the data received as input from the zynq as such.

```
MEM_READ:
process(clk)
begin
   if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if ((hSyncCounter > hBackPorch) and (hSyncCounter <= hBackPorch+hDataLen)) then
            mem(conv_integer(data(19 downto 0))) <= data(31 downto 20);--"111100000000";
       end if;
   end if;
end process;
```

Data being an input signal. 
31 downto 20 consist of the RGB value of the pixel. 
and 19 downto 0 is the adress of i gave from the C.

19 downto 0 is just the grid position in the image and not a specific ram location or something like that, but where is the `mem` I create in the PL stored, or made of? Is it just a big giant mux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use your design tools to check what the synthesizer has done with `mem`.

Check the RTL schematic first, and make sure it looks 'sane' (i.e. make sure `mem` appears as some form of RAM). The RTL schematic shows you the non-architecture specific synthesized HDL.

Then check the "Technology Schematic" (I think that's what Xilinx calls it, at least in ISE), which shows you what the optimization/architecture specific synthesis has done with your design. This should show a `mem` mapped to block RAM(s), or explain what the synthesizer has decided to do with your construct.

Comment: So.. It appears to me that `mem` has become a one giant mux.. 
Is it possible to see how much logic it uses.. ?